# Vue.jsで書かれたデータバインディングのソースコードをNuxt.jsに書き換えたい。

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

#### 実現したいこと

Vue.jsのX-templateのソースコードから、単一ファイルコンポーネントのソースコードに書き換えたいです。

#### 発生している問題

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

#### 該当する元のソースコード

```
<template>
  <div id="vue">
    <h2>These are some examples of how to do two-way bindings</h2>
    <child v-model="stuff" />
    {{ stuff }}
    <hr>
    <selector v-model="selected" /> -->
    {{ selected }}
    <hr>
    <multi-sync :first_name.sync="user.first_name" :second_name.sync="user.second_name" :third_name.sync="user.third_name" :forth_name.sync="user.forth_name" :fifth_name.sync="user.fifth_name">
      </muti-sync>
      {{ user }}
      <hr>
      <multi-field v-model="user2" />
      {{ user2 }}
    </multi-sync>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    child: {
      props: ['value'],
      template: '<input v-model="interface">',
      computed: {
        interface: {
          get () {
            return this.value
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('input', val)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    selector: {
      props: {
        value: {
          type: Array,
          default: [] // value for multi-select must be array, not undefined
        }
      },
      template: '<select v-model="interface" multiple><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>',
      computed: {
        interface: {
          get () {
            return this.value
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('input', val)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    //! ここが重要！
    multiSync: {
      props: ['', '', '', '', ''],
      template: `
        <div>
          <input v-model="sync_first_name">
          <input v-model="sync_second_name">
          <input v-model="sync_third_name">
          <input v-model="sync_forth_name">
          <input v-model="sync_fifth_name">
          </div>`,
      computed: {
        sync_first_name: {
          get () {
            return this.first_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:first_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_second_name: {
          get () {
            return this.second_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:second_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_third_name: {
          get () {
            return this.third_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:third_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_forth_name: {
          get () {
            return this.forth_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:forth_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_fifth_name: {
          get () {
            return this.fifth_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:fifth_name', val)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    multiField: {
      props: {
        value: {
          type: Object,
          default: {
            first_name: '',
            second_name: '',
            third_name: '',
            forth_name: '',
            fifth_name: ''
          }
        }
      },
      template: `
        <div>
          <input v-model="buffer.first_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
          <input v-model="buffer.second_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
                    <input v-model="buffer.third_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
                    <input v-model="buffer.forth_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
                    <input v-model="buffer.fifth_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
        </div>`,
      data () {
        return {
          buffer: Object.assign({}, this.value)
        }
      },
      watch: {
        value: {
          handler () {
            this.buffer = Object.assign({}, this.value)
          },
          deep: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      stuff: '',
      selected: [],
      user: {
      },
      user2: {
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### 試したこと

[【Vue.js】コンポーネントのtemplateの書き方まとめ](https://qiita.com/seya/items/93a0055c8fdab62d584f)
こちらの記事を参考に、以下のソースコードに書き換えた見ましたが解決に至りませんでした。

```
<template>
  <div id="vue">
    <h2>These are some examples of how to do two-way bindings</h2>
    <child v-model="stuff" />
    {{ stuff }}
    <hr>
    <selector v-model="selected" />
    {{ selected }}
    <hr>
    <div>
      <input v-model="sync_first_name">
      <input v-model="sync_second_name">
      <input v-model="sync_third_name">
      <input v-model="sync_forth_name">
      <input v-model="sync_fifth_name">
    </div>
    <multi-sync :first_name.sync="user.first_name" :second_name.sync="user.second_name" :third_name.sync="user.third_name" :forth_name.sync="user.forth_name" :fifth_name.sync="user.fifth_name">
      </muti-sync>
      {{ user }}
      <hr>
      <div>
        <input v-model="buffer.first_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
        <input v-model="buffer.second_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
        <input v-model="buffer.third_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
        <input v-model="buffer.forth_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
        <input v-model="buffer.fifth_name" @input="$emit('input', buffer)">
      </div>
      <multi-field v-model="user2" />
      {{ user2 }}
    </multi-sync>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    child: {
      props: ['value'],
      template: '<input v-model="interface">',
      computed: {
        interface: {
          get () {
            return this.value
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('input', val)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    selector: {
      props: {
        value: {
          type: Array,
          default: [] // value for multi-select must be array, not undefined
        }
      },
      template: '<select v-model="interface" multiple><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>',
      computed: {
        interface: {
          get () {
            return this.value
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('input', val)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    //! ここが重要！
    multiSync: {
      props: ['', '', '', '', ''],
      computed: {
        sync_first_name: {
          get () {
            return this.first_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:first_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_second_name: {
          get () {
            return this.second_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:second_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_third_name: {
          get () {
            return this.third_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:third_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_forth_name: {
          get () {
            return this.forth_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:forth_name', val)
          }
        },
        sync_fifth_name: {
          get () {
            return this.fifth_name
          },
          set (val) {
            this.$emit('update:fifth_name', val)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    multiField: {
      props: {
        value: {
          type: Object,
          default: {
            first_name: '',
            second_name: '',
            third_name: '',
            forth_name: '',
            fifth_name: ''
          }
        }
      },
      data () {
        return {
          buffer: Object.assign({}, this.value)
        }
      },
      watch: {
        value: {
          handler () {
            this.buffer = Object.assign({}, this.value)
          },
          deep: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      stuff: '',
      selected: [],
      user: {
      },
      user2: {
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `template: '<input v-model="interface">',` 、`template: '<select v-model="interface" multiple><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>',`のような事前コンパイル外のtemplateをもった子コンポネがあるようですが……

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/238093